# Force https on index.php

Tags: php, apache

I'm running apache and I would like to force https only on the root page (www.domain.com) which is index.php. Any other pages I would like to leave up to the user. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == false)
  header("Location: https://www.domain.com/");
```

Or, a better way:

```
$ssl = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? true:false;
if (!$ssl)
  header("Location: https://www.domain.com/");
```

This is a little PHP hack. It can be done in a better way using `.htaccess`.

Comment: the $ssl php hack works perfect :) i'll hit accept answer when i can